# Workflow outbound message error : org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad envelope tag: error

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage

We have an outbound message that goes from salesforce.com to a endpoint `https://qaapi.aetna.com/v2/eventtypes/12~9505/events`.

When the message is sent from salesforce it gets stuck in the salesforce queue with the following delivery failure reason:

> org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad envelope tag: error

I am sending only two fields as payload.Below is the snapshot of my workflow
[image]

Any idea whaat might be causing this issue.Is it because of some authentication problem.?

How is the authentication performed when I am hitting the endpoint.Just adding the Remote site setting will do ?